Nested Routing is working on Localhost but not in production in both Netlify and Vercel
This is my App.js Code where I've defined all the routing and then next is index.js code.
// App.js
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

// Pages
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import ContactUs from "./pages/utils/ContactUs";
import AboutUs from "./pages/utils/AboutUs";
import VideoTemplate from "./pages/VideoTemplate";
import VideoGallery from "./pages/VideoGallery";
import VideoPlayer from "./pages/utils/VideoPlayer";
import GenTemplate from "./pages/GenTemplate";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import DubVideo from "./pages/DubVideo";
import DubConsole from "./pages/DubConsole";
import Trash from "./pages/Trash";
import Settings from "./pages/Settings";
import NotLoggedIn from "./pages/NotLoggedIn";
import PageNotFound from "./pages/PageNotFound";
import Test from "./pages/Test";
import Context from "./pages/utils/Context";
import Pricing from "./pages/Pricing";

// Firebase Libraries
import { auth } from "./pages/auths/firebase";
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

import Backdrop from "@mui/material/Backdrop";
import CircularProgress from "@mui/material/CircularProgress";

const LoaderPage = () => {
  return (
    <Backdrop
      sx={{ color: "#fff", zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
      open={true}
    >
      <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
    </Backdrop>
  );
};

function App() {
  const debug = true;
  const serverIp = "http://localhost:5000";
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const {
    checkingUserAuth,
    setCheckingUserAuth,
    authUser,
    setAuthUser,
    ip,
    setIp,
  } = useContext(Context);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        {/* Home Routes */}
        <Route index path="/" element={<Home authUser={authUser} />} />
        <Route path="home" element={<Home authUser={authUser} />} />
        <Route path="contact-us" element={<ContactUs authUser={authUser} />} />
        <Route path="about-us" element={<AboutUs authUser={authUser} />} />
        <Route
          path="test"
          element={<Test authUser={authUser} serverIp={serverIp} />}
        />

        {/* Video Gallery and Play */}
        <Route path="play" element={<VideoTemplate authUser={authUser} />}>
          <Route path="all" element={<VideoGallery authUser={authUser} />} />
          <Route path=":id" element={<VideoPlayer authUser={authUser} />} />
        </Route>

        {/* AI Generation Pages */}
        <Route path="gen" element={<GenTemplate authUser={authUser} />}>
          {authUser ? (
            <>
              <Route
                path="dashboard"
                element={
                  <Dashboard authUser={authUser} ip={ip} serverIp={serverIp} />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="dub-video"
                element={
                  <DubVideo authUser={authUser} ip={ip} serverIp={serverIp} />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="dub-console"
                element={
                  <DubConsole authUser={authUser} ip={ip} serverIp={serverIp} />
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="trash"
                element={<Trash authUser={authUser} serverIp={serverIp} />}
              />
              <Route
                path="pricing"
                element={<Pricing authUser={authUser} serverIp={serverIp} />}
              />

              <Route
                path="settings"
                element={<Settings authUser={authUser} serverIp={serverIp} />}
              />
            </>
          ) : (
            <Route
              path="*"
              element={checkingUserAuth ? <LoaderPage /> : <NotLoggedIn />}
            />
          )}
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


This is index.js file where I've declared the BrowserRouter.
// index.js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
// import { Analytics } from "@vercel/analytics/react";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import ContextProvider from "./pages/utils/ContextProvider";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
\<React.StrictMode\>
\<BrowserRouter\>
\<ContextProvider\>
\<App /\>
\</ContextProvider\>
\</BrowserRouter\>
\</React.StrictMode\>
);


The base routes are woring in production but then the nested routes are not working and I've tried multiple method including the vercel.json for vercel and _redirect file in Netlify but it's not working.

